# Contents of gitignore duplicated on pull

Tags: git, gitignore, gitkraken

When one particular user pulls a repo (using GitKraken), the gitignore file immediately is added as a work in progress. When he opens the file, the contents are duplicated. This:

```
# Placing a # in front of any of the items listed below (e.g., #analyzer) will  #
# allow these items to be pushed to your Git repository. Keep in mind the more  #
# files you push to your repository, the more your performance may be affected. #
#################################################################################

/Output
/Analyzer
/FileSync
/Project/Users
/.svn
**/Thumbs.db

#################################################################################
# Add items to be ignored below                                                 #
#################################################################################

**/Corel Auto-Preserve
*.bak
/.ini
```

turns into this:

```
# Placing a # in front of any of the items listed below (e.g., #analyzer) will #
# allow these items to be pushed to your Git repository. Keep in mind the more #
# files you push to your repository, the more your performance may be affected. #
#################################################################################

/Output
/Analyzer
/FileSync
/Project/Users
/.svn
**/Thumbs.db

#################################################################################
# Add items to be ignored below #
#################################################################################

#################################################################################
# Placing a # in front of any of the items listed below (e.g., #analyzer) will #
# allow these items to be pushed to your Git repository. Keep in mind the more #
# files you push to your repository, the more your performance may be affected. #
#################################################################################



/Output
/Analyzer
/FileSync
/Project/Users
/.svn
**/Thumbs.db



#################################################################################
# Add items to be ignored below #
#################################################################################



**/Corel Auto-Preserve
*.bak
/.ini
```

My current solution to him is to simply discard the change and keep going with the rest of his work.

Any ideas as to why this is happening and how to prevent it?

Comment: What does that user see when they run `git check-attr -a .gitignore`?

Comment: Nothing happens. No output at all.